# Is this correct?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Studying for my exam and I want to know if this code is correct.
I have just signed up for this site so I'm sorry if anything wrong with my question.

This code finds the first zero value in an array. If none found, It makes SI point to the last array element.

```
Data Segment
array DW -3, 7, 20, 10, 0, 4, 9
End Segment

Code Segment

MOV SI, OFFSET array
MOV CX, LENGTHOF array
MOV AX, 0
L1:
MOV AX, [SI]
CMP AX, 0
JE FOUND
JCXZ NOT FOUND
ADD SI, 2
LOOP L1
FOUND:
RET

NOT FOUND: 
MOV SI, 12
END
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your program;

1. If value isn't found, program will just run off and execute whatever is past **MOV SI, 12**.
2. **JCXZ** is redundant as **LOOP** already looks after testing CX.
3. **LOOP** will only decrement by 1, so you're going to be testing twice as many values as you're expecting.

Following is an example in NASM and other than **OFFSET** and **LENGTHOF** they are essentially the same.

```
         org    0x100               ; Origin of code (Maybe EMU8086 doesn't need this)

         mov    si, Values          ; Nothing wrong with using Array either
         mov    cx, (VEnd-Values)/2 ; Actual number of words in array

    L0:  lodsw                      ; Loads AX with value pointed to by SI and inc's SI.
         cmp    ax, 0
         jz     Done
         loop   L0                  ; Will continue until CX = 0

  Done:  dec    si
         dec    si                  ; Point back to last value read
         ret                        ; Terminate program

Values: dw  -3, 7, 20, 10, 0, 4, 9
VEnd:   db  0
```

I would recommend not submitting this example as your answer, but as your code is very close to workable, it's should be too much of a challenge to modify yours to work even with using **mov ax,[si]**.

Comment: `jcxz` is only redundant if the length can't be zero.  It should be outside the loop, though.  (The `loop` instruction only checks CX after decrementing, so entering a loop with CX=0 means 2^16 iterations).  Yes the OP is using it inappropriately, arguably wrong, though.